# React Native - Why we use the after property in the CameraRoll.getPhotos()?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a photo app, so, for this reason i am leaning the whole `CameraRoll` module from the official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll#getphotos) to make everything clear. Please can anyone tell why we use the `after` property in `CameraRoll.getPhotos()` and what string value does it take? The documentation is not enough to understand. A little example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll#getphotos) says, you just need to set it as `end_cursor` of your previous call to fetch more photos.

Here's a simple example on how you can use it:

```
state = {
    lastCursor: (null : ?string),
};

getPhotos = () => 
    var fetchParams = {
        first: 10,
    }
    if (this.state.lastCursor) {
        fetchParams.after = this.state.lastCursor;
    }
    CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams).then(result => {
        this.setState({lastCursor: result.page_info.end_cursor});
  });
```

You can see a full example of using it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.27-stable/Examples/UIExplorer/CameraRollView.js#L148-L150).

Comment: For what purpose it is used? What is the purpose of using this property? And what is this `lastCursor: (null : ?string)` can you please tell?

Comment: It means if the `lastCursor` is `null` then do `nothing` else `string`, so, what is this `string`?

Comment: From the example It looks like it is used when you need to fetch more photos, so it must match the end_cursor of the previous call to fetch rest of the photos.

Comment: So, it means that it is used to determine whether we have more photos in camera roll or not, and the value of `page_info.end_cursor` will be the value of the `after` in the current call, right?

Comment: I guess that's correct. It is not mentioned clearly in the documents or in the code, but that seems logical